# how to manage tags and categories in liferay portal remotely?

Tags: tags, liferay, categories, portal

I have recently been working with liferay portal 6.2 GA3. I use tags and categories for my documents, but I can only work with them properly when on a local PC. When i access this portal from a remote PC I can not load this tags and categories at Site Administrator --> content --> tags or categories. On the screen a loading image can be seen!
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please check the networks tab of the development tools of your browser for any error message when loading resources. And add the result to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have solved the problem, just need to add permission for the PC to use json service in Portal-ex.properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply! I have solved the problem, just need to add permission for the PC to use json service in Portal-ex.properties

```
json.service.auth.token.hosts.allowed=127.0.0.1, CLIENT_IP
jsonws.web.service.public.methods=*
jsonws.servlet.hosts.allowed=127.0.0.1, CLIENT_IP
```

After that, we need to restart the portal.
Attention: Only client IP allowed can use the categories to annotate documents (chose categories for the annotating document.